# Is it possible to pull a React component prop data using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am building a Chrome Extension that pulls various data points from the DOM. The website that I am pulling data from was built with React and I was curious if there was a way to get prop data from the hidden React DOM using javascript running from within the Chrome Extension.

For example, I am trying to get the React ID of specific posts in a forum thread. I can inspect the React component using the React Dev Tools but haven't been successful in trying to retrieve those data points.

I'm curious to see if anyone knows a way to retrieve data from the React DOM of an external site.

Comment: The react dev tools use a global hook called `__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__`  [docs](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools#the-react-tab-doesnt-show-up). Have you examined the [source](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__&type=) yet?

Comment: I have read a few posts on Stackoverflow mentioning that the global hook can be used. Any idea how I could proceed with querying the React DOM for a specific component using the __REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__?